# Javascript form.submit stuck in a loop

Tags: javascript, forms, submit, reload

I'm writing an auto-login script for an internal site at work.  In some very basic preliminary testing, I've found that my script is submitting the form endlessly.  It's in the form of a chrome extension.  The form is in ASP.NET.  Here's the code:

```
    bbform = document.forms['aspnetForm'];
usr = bbform.elements["ctl00$content$txtUserName"];
pass = bbform.elements["ctl00$content$txtPassword"];


usr.value = 'anyusername';
pass.value = 'P@ssword1';
bbform.submit;
```

What am I missing?  Needless to say, I'm not completing the login process because the form keeps submitting itself.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you mean `bbform.submit()` instead of `bbform.submit`?

Comment: @hubbahubba : do you call this function from somewhere? may be on a submit button's click ?